# Best practices for partial responses with Spring HATEOAS

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I'm writing a multiuser application in which requests for a given resource (say, `/people/4`) will return differing levels of detail depending on the user performing the request (for example, user 4 or a support representative would see the entire resource, while other users would not see certain fields such as the user's e-mail address).

Spring HATEOAS has thorough support for building links, but the main `ResourceAssember` interface only provides a single adapter method that takes a domain object and returns a resource object, with no provision for additional parameters (such as the current Spring Security user), and neither `ResourceSupport` nor `Resource<T>` provides facilities for filtering the fields returned.

The approach I'm currently leaning toward is having the implementation of `toResource` for `ResourceAssembler<Customer, CustomerResource>` manually dig out the current Spring Security credentials and apply filtering at that point, essentially hand-writing a multi-stage copy constructor that will add public fields, then for-friends fields, then private fields to the resource object.

Is there a more integrated, especially declarative, way to handle the task, or is this the best solution available now? Will this approach integrate with the Spring Data REST controller, or will I have to reimplement paging and so forth if I want to handle the assembly myself?

Comment: what about using column-level security in the database?

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan That doesn't address this issue for several reasons. (1) The field filtering needs to happen at a high level, filtering based on per-object settings, and eventually providing for query-specified fields. (2) The Spring Data (or plain JPA) API doesn't interface with database-level column restrictions, at least not in a sane and predictable manner. (3) A substantial portion of the data store won't be SQL anyhow.

Comment: @chrylis hey, have you found any decent solution for this?